# How to drive this specific laser

Tags: pulse, laser, optoelectronics, laser-diode, laser-driver

I've done just a circuit to drive an old laser and it was like this one:

[image]

I was wondering if it could be suitable for driving the laser whose datasheet is reported below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have these requirements:

1. I need a pulse frequency equal to 50kHz. I cannot see the maximum frequency allowed by this specific laser. Do you see something which can help me find it?
2. The maximum pulse length for this laser is 150ns. I'd like to use 100ns.

So, my question is: do you think this kind of circuit could be good for this laser? If not, which modifications will you apply?

Comment: You don't need to post images of the data sheet; just the link will do. I don't see how your circuit can work; won't the capacitor get charged up and isn't the 1N4007 really, really slow for anything like a decent modulation rate. You also need to avoid turning the laser fully off if you want fast data throughput (aka avoid extinction).

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for these indications. About your second observation: which variations will you apply to avoid turning the laser fully off?

Comment: You haven't got a circuit that makes sense, you have an unspecified laser that appears to produce a light output that is several orders of magnitude brighter than the sun in the middle of summer, you have an unspecified application and an unknown modulation frequency and you are asking for modifications to your original circuit. Did I read that correctly?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not expert of lasers, hence I don't know the specific requirements to design a driver circuit. The input signal is a pulse train with 100ns of high value and 50kHz frequency, hence duty 2%. This laser has a maximum emitted power of 640W. I need to use 100W.

Comment: You are playing with fire here! A 640W output power LASER is not a toy, is a weapon! If you are asking here you probably have not the expertise to do anything safe with that. BTW, in some jurisdictions operating such a laser could indeed be considered operating a weapon, and so could require a special license. For example, in Europe LASERs sold as pointers must be limited to ***1mW***, because higher power LASERs are too dangerous and can blind people (even permanently).

Comment: BTW Activating such a beast means that even a minimal partial reflection of the beam (say 1%) could permanently destroy your retinas if you don't wear appropriate protections. See this page: [Laser Radiation Safety Advice (UK government)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/laser-radiation-safety-advice/laser-radiation-safety-advice). Class 4 lasers (anything above 500mW) are not safe for consumer use.

Comment: This is also relevant: https://www.laserpointersafety.com/rules-general/intllaws/intllaws.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read first something like [this](https://www.lasercomponents.com/de/?embedded=1&file=fileadmin/user_upload/home/Datasheets/lc/application-reports/lc-electronics/drive-electronics-pulsed-laser-diodes.pdf&no_cache=1).

A schematic like this could be used, but remember that a Laser with this power is not for newbies ...
**SAFETY** first.
**If you don't know, don't even try to use it.**

[image]

Here is a sample of simulation. Characteristics of Laser diode "guessed".

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'll read the guide to understand it better. Can you explain me the role of L1 and why an avalanche transistor (instead of a normal transistor) should be utilized?

Comment: Avalanche transistors (very special use) are used for generating a very fast pulse. Don't mix with "thermic avalanche" which destroy immediately the transistor if not well "cooled". L1 is used for limiting the di/dt. Not limiting this value should destroy the transistor, remember L1 is used as "current feedback".